# can not resolve symbol JobIntentService

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-jobscheduler

Following `build.gradle` configuration on my project

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.tt"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    generatedDensities = []
}
```

And Following support library i have compiled

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
```

When i have trying to import `JobIntentService` class its not resolve.Below link to i am trying to implement

[JobIntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html)

Comment: for androidx: implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.1'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JobIntentService was added in support library version **26.1.0** from package `com.android.support:support-compat`.

So, update your gradle version for support library.

For AndroidX:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.1'
```

Latest stable version is available in [Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core)

Comment: Thank you @rupinderjeet for save my day.

Comment: @user9289038 While at it, make sure your support library version matches your compile SDK version.

Comment: compile SDK version 27 and support library version now 27.0.2

Answer (score 1):

You need this :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case  implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0' caused many error messages about incompability, so

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:<you_target_platform_ver>"
```

helped.